# Automatic DHCP after Softether VPN Client starts via SystemD

Tags: networking, vpn, systemd

Long story short: I have this SystemD unit for my Softether VPN client:

```
[Unit]
Description=SoftEther VPN Client
After=network.target
Wants=softethervpn-server.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/srv/vpnserver/vpnclient start
ExecStop=/srv/vpnserver/vpnclient stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now all that is missing to call `dhclient vpn_vpn` to finalize the link.

How do I best automate that? As far as I know, there is a one-shot type for Systemd units...but honestly I copy-pasted most of mine bar a few exceptions.

Thanks and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type of the service from `forking` to `simple`, you could add the `ExecStartPost=` line to execute a command after the process is started.

Or you could write another .service file for the dhcp_client of and set `After=softether-client.service` or whatever you called your client service. Then make the service `Type=oneshot` and `ExecStart=<path_to_dhcp_client_executable> vpn_vpn`.

Check the [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) and [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) documentation for more info.

I am not 100% sure of this though. Maybe someone more competent might give a better answer.

I hope this helps !